# sun.misc.Perf documentation or alternative

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, jvm

I understand that the `sun.*` packages are not part of the official Java API. However, I need to use some functionality similar to what `Perf` offers: specifically Basic JVM Metrics (Heap, Threads, PermGen, etc), JvmStat counters to GC, etc. Does anybody know a wrapper library around `Perf` and `PerfInstrumentation` which comes with a good documentation.

I need to use it as an API so e.g. the VisualVM's Tracer plugin is not good enough. Anybody has a comment on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are wrapper around JVM perfcounters in [jvm-attach](https://github.com/gridkit/jvm-attach) library, though documentation is not any better (i.e. it is absent).

[jvm-attach](https://github.com/gridkit/jvm-attach) library itself is a wrapper around JVM diagnostic interfaces including heap dumps, JMX etc